# QMAKE_QMAKE with symbolic link to qmake

Tags: qt, symlink, qmake

I need to get path of folder with my qt in pro file.
I used [QMAKE_QMAKE](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-qmake) and everything worked.

But now I created a symbolic link to qmake in ~/.local/bin to make it easier to call qmake.

```
qmake-linux -> /home/andrei/Qt/Qt-v5.13.0/Linux/bin/qmake*
```

And now I ran into the problem that qmake, launched by a symbolic link, contains in the variable QMAKE_QMAKE not the path to the executable file, but the path to the symbolic link.

```
Info: creating stash file /home/andrei/worker/githubworker/github-worker/build/.qmake.stash
Project MESSAGE: QT_DIR = /home/andrei/.local/bin
```

Maybe it is important:  I build qt from sources.

Maybe there are ways to get qmake paths or folders with qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory where the qmake executable is located can be retrieved with `$$[QT_HOST_BINS]`. This is a [qmake property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-environment-reference.html#properties).

Call `qmake -query` to see a list of available properties.